# Is there a way to remove or remap columns for ONLY THE 1ST ROW? (CSV output)

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am using an Azure Data Flow to do many data transformations and finally output a tab-delimited text file.

I am looking for a way to totally remove 2 Columns from ONLY the first row...
And then ONLY for the first row, all the columns after that should "slide left".

Example:
(I'm using a tab-delimited list, but I will use commas here for visibility)

Lets say I have the following input:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5

6, 7, 8, 9, 10

11, 12, 13, 14, 15

I would like to remove 2 columns from the 1st row, so I would like the output to be:

1, 4, 5

6, 7, 8, 9, 10

11, 12, 13, 14, 15

(in this example the columns containing 2 and 3 are removed)

Additionally.  If it is REQUIRED that the same number of columns are in each row I could move the empty columns to the end of the first row, example:

1, 4, 5, ,

6, 7, 8, 9, 10

11, 12, 13, 14, 15

---

I have used Derived Columns to implement dynamic logic to BLANK OUT the values on the 1st row.. However, I need to remove the entire fields not just BLANK OUT the values.

I have also used mapping to remove columns, but of course that removes the column from ALL the rows, and in my scenario I need to ONLY remove the tabs/columns for the FIRST row.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Can you show us the examples? Like the input data and the output data you expected.

Comment: thanks @LeonYue I have added an example

Comment: Per my experience, it will change the schema of the csv file. The fist row will considered as the schema. But the output your expected, change the schema. We can not delete the column which not change the schema.  Data Factory can't achieve that.

Comment: i find it hard to believe that it's not possible..  it may be tricky but it's definitely not impossible.  can't i shift rows to the left for the first row somehow?  maybe i can move the 2 "empty" fields to the END of the first row so it won't "change the schema", while still moving everything to the left?  if that is a big concern I could keep the same number of columns and add blank columns to the END of the line.  Or something like that...  Or perhaps somehow append a new/different row to the top of the output?

Comment: or "union" another row to the top of the output

Comment: Yes, Union should work here to combine 2 different dissimilar schemas

Comment: Thanks Mark!  It does appear easier than I even thought.  I am not completed with the mods yet but it appears Union (by Position) is going to allow me to get there.  if you would like to leave something like that as an answer i will accept it!!!

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT also this might be a coincidence but any chance you're kromerbigdata, and this is your blog article?? :), I did have a question about this article https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/02/22/azure-data-factory-data-flows-working-with-multiple-files/   i cannot get this format working: (ab|def)  <– match files with ab or def could you verify that functionality made it to ADF

Comment: @JBoothUA I just approved your comments on the blog and I'll reply there to get you working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Union transformation to combine dissimilar schemas in a data flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union

Comment: i was able to accomplish this.  I split off my first row.  I re-selected/re-mapped to remove the columns, and then I did a Union "By Position" in order to add it back.  Much easier than I was fearing!